# Initial mysql password not set after installation on CentOS 8 machine

Tags: mysql, centos

I installed mysql on my CentOS 8 machine. I installed the .rpm file, then used "dnf install mysql-server", after which I start the application with systemctl start mysql, but the log file doesn't contain the initial root password so I'm unable to log in to configure mysql.

What am I doing wrong? Or where is the initial password hidden?

Cheers,
PW

Comment: what "log" file did you check? it should be in the error logs.

Comment: /var/log/mysqld.log

Comment: Try running `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`

Comment: User error: The data directory contained files from a previous attempt to enable mysql. I deleted the directory and restarted mysql. It work this time.